# Inherit Color Scheme from Site in App

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, ios-app

First of all, let me say I love the appearance of the iOS SE App. The subtle blue gradients are top notch, but it doesn't break from the iOS 7 style.

I do get a little lost in it, especially browsing different SE sites.

So I propose: What might enhance it even further would be to inherit the color scheme from the site you're viewing, especially in content pages. It wouldn't be actually reinventing any color scheme. Should be as simple* as copying a few colors from the site's CSS.

<sub>* Simple to wave my arms from my couch. Not necessarily simple to implement for the developers doing the *actual* work</sub>

Comment: Custom sites are more than a few different colors.

Comment: Without question they are much more than colors! But a lot of the other detail is lost/muddied on a small screen (up/down icons, etc). I propose keep those generic, and only change the colors. At least for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an idea we considered during the initial creation of our Android application and we decided against it. While the actual Android and iOS applications themselves don't have to be identical (and in fact they're not, their design is platform-specific) I think that high level decisions like this one should apply to both.

Having different color schemes for different sites would be a jarring experience unless you're already an active member of Stack Exchange and know that if you were on the website that's what the case would be. Since the mobile application's feed combines items from so many different websites, we decided that it would be a weird experience for a new user to tap on things in it and have their application reskin.

That said, this is a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: Was there consideration of the fact it might be jarring to see the website in one color and the app in a different color? Initial SE exposure will be almost exclusively through the website (where of course clicking "hot network questions" has these
 same theme changes

Comment: Sorry I'm paraphrasing a conversion that took place around 6 months ago so I may not have correctly described it. I would argue with your statement regarding initial exposure, and I'd say that it's a jarring experience with hot questions on the site too (specially since you can go somewhere where you it's not only a different UI but you aren't even logged in!)

Comment: It's also important to note that on the website the sites each live as separate communities, where as on the mobile apps you're using the Stack Exchange network's application rather than simply looking at 100+ sites clumped together in one application. Cohesion is important in this case.

Comment: I respect that there *was* a discussion of it, and accept that the sites are different communities while app is one clump

Comment: I do question your "I would argue with your statement regarding initial exposure". I doubt anyone would download the app who hasn't at least visited the site before, if only through a google search (which at least for SO is almost always the first result)